# How is my React hook not respecting default?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component like this

```js
export default function Panel() {
  const rpcClient = RpcClient.getInstance(PLUGIN_ID);

  setupOnce(rpcClient);

  const [currentXMPID, setCurrentXMPID] = useState<string | null>(null);

  function isAttachStorageOn(): boolean {
    if (!currentXMPID) {
      return false;
    }

    // real code looks at a cookie
    return true;
  }

  // This panel is frequently re-rendered and we need to use saved setting if XMP ID was retrieved already
  const renderAttachState = isAttachStorageOn();


  // this is outputting true
  console.log('set attach checked default to', renderAttachState);

  const [isAttachChecked, setAttachChecked] = useState(renderAttachState);

  // this is outputting false
  console.log('after using state', isAttachChecked);

  // This will only fire once
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const xmpID = await rpcClient.getXMPID();

      setCurrentXMPID(xmpID);
      setAttachChecked(isAttachStorageOn());
    })();
  }, []);

  return <div>Just a test</div>;
}
```

I am bewildered as it logs `true` and then `false`. This seems to make zero sense. I am running this component in an app I have limited control over. I did find that this component is being re-rendered a lot and am wondering if there could be issue around that... but even if it re-renders 1000 times it should do so in order such that the `console.log`s match up.

**Update**

It seems as though the hook is staying as whatever value is first given in the `useEffect` which is only run once. If I set `setAttachChecked` to `bananas` in that method, no subsequent calls are updating it.

Comment: Post the entire file's code

Comment: I believe `renderAttachState` is a prop or a argument to the function ( if this code is inside a custom hook ) . when passing `renderAttachState` to the useState it is just the initial value . so on the first render you should see both the values printing the same result . But the moment you are start updating the state your `isAttachChecked` will just be the latest value . so are you changing the value of `isAttachChecked` using `setAttachChecked` ?

Comment: I will try and truncate this file down to be digestable for SO :)

Comment: Updated the question to show whole component after i deleted a bunch of code that doesn't relate, while leaving some to get how it works (in case the use effect logic has to do with issue)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure whether or not this is the solution you are looking for.

`useState` is used to set default value. This line here

`console.log('after using state', isAttachChecked);`

is for displaying `isAttachChecked` value. And it might be equal to the `defaultValue` for the first time, but might not be after that even though you called it after `useState` hook.

Answer (score 0):

I should just be doing  `const [isAttachChecked, setAttachChecked] = useState(false);`

No changes in render should be expected to actually update `isAttachChecked`. Since I care about return of `isAttachStorageOn`, which changes value based upon `currentXMPID`, all I needed to do was make `useEffect` do:

`}, [currentXMPID]);`